# Move my toolbar up or down based on keyboard and the predictive text view iOS 8

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard, ios8

I am developing a chat application which does have a toolbar(with `UITextView` and other buttons) at the bottom of chat screen same as whatsapp which moves up and down depending on keyboard visibility, which was working fine till iOS 7.

I have used `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` based on which i used to fetch the keyboard frame using below code

```
  CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

and set the frame of toolbar accordingly.

but it is not working on iOS 8 with predictive text.
Any Help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

`UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` not getting fired up when predictive text view moved up or down.

Appending snapshots

[image: Image with predictive text] [image]

Comment: Have you test with Xcode6.1 beta? I don't see any deprecated in UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification for iOS8

Comment: I don't know what happened but when i deleted the derived data and restarted the Xcode then it started working....

Comment: Take a look at my solution in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213681/ios-8-keyboard-hides-my-textview/26226732#26226732

Comment: @newton_guima problem already solved buddy. Thanks anyways..

Comment: @pankaj Please post the solution you arrived at by answering your own question so that others (like myself) can benefit from how you ended up solving this. Thanks.

Comment: @devios as i have mentioned above in comments that when i deleted all derived data from Xcode then my problem goes away.
Still i have posted an answer to help others as how this functionality is done. Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25956919/1606125

Comment: @pankaj Sorry I missed that!

Answer (score -1):

## iOS 10, 9 all the way down to 5

> **UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification**
>
> Posted immediately after a change in the keyboard’s frame.
>
> The notification object is nil. The userInfo dictionary contains information about the keyboard. Use the keys described in Keyboard Notification User Info Keys to get the location and size of the keyboard from the userInfo dictionary.

*Tested on iPhone 6, iOS 10, 9, 8.4 (linked, built, ran, see logs below).*

The `NSNotification` dictionary shows the inversion of `CGRect` values in `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` & `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`, and all 4 `UIKeyboard__Notification` are fired when the predictive accessory view is changed.

**Swift 3**

```
func addObserver(forName: Notification.Name) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: forName,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: OperationQueue.main)
    { (note:Notification!) -> Void in
        print("\(forName): \(note)")
    }
}

addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillShow)
addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardDidShow)
addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame)
addObserver(forName: .UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame)
```

**Turning Predictive ON**

[image]

*log:*

> UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:
>   UIKeyboardWillShowNotification:
>   UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification:
>   UIKeyboardDidShowNotification:
>   userInfo = {
>           UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {375, 258}}";
>           UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {187.5, 554.5}";
>           UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {187.5, 538}";
>           UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 442}, {375, 225}}";
>           UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 409}, {375, 258}}";
>       }

**Turning Predictive OFF**

[image]

*log:*

> UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:
>   UIKeyboardWillShowNotification:
>   UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification:
>   UIKeyboardDidShowNotification:
>   userInfo = {
>           UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {375, 225}}";
>           UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {187.5, 538}";
>           UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {187.5, 554.5}";
>           UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 409}, {375, 258}}";
>           UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 442}, {375, 225}}";
>       }

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-25946121) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-25946121).